# Tikz picture works in "report" class but not in "beamer" class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, report

I have to present my bachelorthesis with a beamer presentation on wednesday. Now I ran into a problem that I do not understand. All I did was copying the code from my thesis where it did work perfectly fine. I even tested it with an MWE for both (report and beamer) and it only worked with the report. When I looked up the problem, most of the solutions where about the path to the file where the data is supposed to be, however there is no path, the data is directly in the code.

This is how it is supposed to look like:
[image: When it works]

This is an MWE that does work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            xtick={0,0.2,...,2},
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            xlabel=LB/LX,
            ylabel={$H_1/H_2$}
            ] 
            \addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]table[meta=x] {
                x y
                0.860 1.156
                1.068 1.806
                1.248 1.197
                1.093 2.377
                1.833 1.143
                0.609 2.332
                0.936 1.017
                1.277 1.099
                0.804 1.279
                0.862 3.040
                0.778 1.888
                0.797 3.099
                1.546 1.004
                0.841 3.729
                0.989 1.736
                1.889 1.000
                0.794 1.277
                0.885 1.158
                0.966 1.256
                0.778 1.888
                0.936 1.0172
                0.863 3.953
                };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{Test}
\end{document}
```

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title[MWE]{MWE}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}{3.3. Interpretation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            xtick={0,0.2,...,2},
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            xlabel=LB/LX,
            ylabel={$H_1/H_2$}
            ] 
            \addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]table[meta=x] {
                x y
                0.860 1.156
                1.068 1.806
                1.248 1.197
                1.093 2.377
                1.833 1.143
                0.609 2.332
                0.936 1.017
                1.277 1.099
                0.804 1.279
                0.862 3.040
                0.778 1.888
                0.797 3.099
                1.546 1.004
                0.841 3.729
                0.989 1.736
                1.889 1.000
                0.794 1.277
                0.885 1.158
                0.966 1.256
                0.778 1.888
                0.936 1.0172
                0.863 3.953};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My guess is that the beamer class can not read or find the data. However I do not understand why. Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: I have no explanation, but, as a workaround, you can make your graphic file as a standalone file, and incorporate the resulting .pdf with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing my spelling mistakes and offering a solution. I tried that and it does look passable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the `[fragile]` option to the frame, **and** add a line-ending to your table, in the sense that

```latex
            0.863 3.953};
```

should be

```latex
               0.863 3.953
            };
```

then it will work:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\title[MWE]{MWE}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{3.3. Interpretation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            xtick={0,0.2,...,2},
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            xlabel=LB/LX,
            ylabel={$H_1/H_2$}
            ] 
            \addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]table[meta=x] {
                x y
                0.860 1.156
                1.068 1.806
                1.248 1.197
                1.093 2.377
                1.833 1.143
                0.609 2.332
                0.936 1.017
                1.277 1.099
                0.804 1.279
                0.862 3.040
                0.778 1.888
                0.797 3.099
                1.546 1.004
                0.841 3.729
                0.989 1.736
                1.889 1.000
                0.794 1.277
                0.885 1.158
                0.966 1.256
                0.778 1.888
                0.936 1.0172
                0.863 3.953
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, you can pre-load your table and then it works:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\title[MWE]{MWE}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{subcaption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{
                x y
                0.860 1.156
                1.068 1.806
                1.248 1.197
                1.093 2.377
                1.833 1.143
                0.609 2.332
                0.936 1.017
                1.277 1.099
                0.804 1.279
                0.862 3.040
                0.778 1.888
                0.797 3.099
                1.546 1.004
                0.841 3.729
                0.989 1.736
                1.889 1.000
                0.794 1.277
                0.885 1.158
                0.966 1.256
                0.778 1.888
                0.936 1.0172
                0.863 3.953
}\mytable


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{3.3. Interpretation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            xtick={0,0.2,...,2},
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            xlabel=LB/LX,
            ylabel={$H_1/H_2$}
            ]
            \addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]table[meta=x] \mytable;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this did work perfectly. Thank you very much.